# MVC4 - Value can not be null. Parameter name: source

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I create a new project in MVC4. I get this error:
`System.ArgumentNullException: Value can not be null.
Parameter name: source.`
The database exists, the table exists and is filled with data.

Any tips?

Controler **ShopController.cs**

```
...  
    SQLEntities DB = new SQLEntities();  

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var x = DB.Types.ToList();          <-Here I get an exception
        return View(x);
    }
...
```

Model **Type.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace xxx.Models
{
    public class Type
    {
        public int TypeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Model **SQLEntities.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace xxx.Models
{
    public class SQLEntities
    {
        public DbSet<Type> Types { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Web.config**

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SQLEntities" connectionString="Data Source=KOMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=myDB;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

The compiler doesn't indicate any error. It was only when he wants to go to `mypage/Shop` getting an exception.

**stack trace**

```
{System.ArgumentNullException: Value can not be null.
Parameter name: source.
       w System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       w Print.Controllers.StoreController.Index() w c:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Print\Print\Controllers\StoreController.cs:wiersz 18
       w lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       w System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       w System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       w System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       w System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
       w System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
       w System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
       w System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       w System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
       w System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()}
```

Comment: *Where* exactly are you getting that exception? Please include the stack trace.

Comment: You didn't add *much* information - please add the complete stack trace.

Comment: Can you provide the complete SQLEntities class, please?

Comment: I'm sorry, I copied from wrong place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `SQLEntities` should inherit from `DbContext`.

Your problem is that `SQLEntities.Types` is clearly null. You shouldn't be required to initialize this property as the EntityFramework will do it automatically when everything is setup correctly.

Change your code to:

```
   public class SQLEntities: DbContext
   {
       public DbSet<Type> Types { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Half a day over this is tiring. Thank you very much.